# Has anyone tested SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services with the Chrome browser?

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services, google-apps

We use [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx) as the primary report engine for our company's internal software development.  It's free with SQL Server and has a lot of functionality.  A well documented problem we run into is incompatibility with the Chrome browser.  Some Reporting Services features work, but some do not. [Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/61bbd25f-43a5-4b90-b5cd-cdc4445148a5)

Has anyone tested this combination on the beta of SQL Server 2012, which is due to be released soon?  Thus far, neither Microsoft nor Google seem that interested in solving this issue.

This is a problem for us because our company uses Google Apps for almost all user productivity applications (mail, docs, etc.), and we consequently prefer that our users use Chrome, but we use C# & SQL Server as our primary software development platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 RC0 Reporting Services does not display reports in Chrome (or at least the reports we've written).  Authentication works, and browsing the report folders works, and even running the report works, including prompts for parameter values, but the reports are empty.  The spinner spins as if it is running the report, just a blank screen returns.  I suspect it has to do with CSS layout issues.

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting, but was hoping for something else.  Thanks.

Comment: Can somebody please tell Microsoft that the browser wars were over 10 years ago? This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested some reports in Chrome 19.0.1+ and SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services 11.0.2100.60, and didn't have any problems, i.e. reports rendered directly off the Report Manager in Chrome fine.

In terms of general incompatibility, iPad support is a big deal where I work, and Reporting Services doesn't appear to support Safari. I suppose you could work around this by giving a direct URL to PDF format ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)) since most devices can probably handle PDF files.

Comment: I found your PDF link interesting.  Good idea.